# What is the interval between two enharmonic notes?

Tags: theory, intervals

The interval between, say, C4 and D4 is a major 2nd.

What is the interval between B#3 and C4?

Is it still a 2nd?

For lack of a better term would it be something like a minor minor 2nd?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have:

- **B# - C: Diminished 2nd** (same as B-Cb)
- B - C: Minor 2nd
- B - C#: Major 2nd (same as Bb - C)
- Bb -C#: Augmented 2nd

If I'm not mistaken, there are also double diminished and double augmented intervals, like Bb - Cx but rarely used

Generally the interval qualities are: Diminished, Minor, Major, Augmented *or* Diminished, Perfect, Augmented.

Comment: Worth mentioning that on a keyboard instrument, this is recognized as a unison, but there is a difference on other instruments such as string instruments (where a sharp is played differently as a flat, e.g. in F#-Gb diminished 2nd).

Comment: @PierreArlaud F#-Gb would be a unison both in a piano and a guitar. What is exactly your point?

Comment: @Shevliaskovic my understanding is that technically, F#-Gb is an enharmonic interval and both notes are separated by a comma. On a violin you would make a slight difference (Bb should not be played exactly the same as a A#), which is impossible on a piano.

Comment: I play double bass and I've never heard of this. I try to play A# and Bb the same. Otherwise how would a violin or double bass play with a piano? won't it sound out of tune in times like this?

Comment: @Shevliaskovic to avoid an extended discussion, I can thankfully redirect you to this answer http://music.stackexchange.com/a/11816. This would in theory be a problem if one violin played an A# and another one a Bb, but having both notes written at the same time on the sheet would seem very experimental to me. The point was: a diminished second is not exactly a unison as there is a very thin difference between a sharp and a flat or between a chromatic and a diatonic tone.

Comment: Didn't know that; I'll take a look. It seems interesting

Comment: @Shevliaskovic obviously string players playing with instruments that have fixed tuning like a piano need to play in the same tuning system, but a string quartet or a string orchestra doesn't have those constraints. This is not really a matter of different *names* for the *same note* but of similar pitches having different *harmonic and melodic functions* in common-practice western music. For example CPE Bach was very fond of diminished octaves (e.g. C to C flat),  which had a different harmonic function from major sevenths (e.g. C to B) and his "spelling" of the notes follows the function.

Comment: Aside from enharmonics in common-practice harmony and/or unequal temperaments, these intervals also pop up in computer notation software - for example if you want to convert some notation from G flat major to F sharp major, that might be described as "transposing the music by an interval of a diminished 2nd".